# Buscar os registros dos últimos 3 meses sql banco oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Baseado na consulta abaixo  :

```
SELECT DTCHAMADO AS DT_ABERTO,
       DTTERMINO AS DT_ENCERRADO, 
       CDCHAMADO AS CHAMADO, 
       NMTITULOCHAMADO AS TITULO, 
       NMRESPONSAVEL AS RESPONSÁVEL, 
       NMSITUACAO AS SITUAÇÃO
FROM VW_HD_CHAMADO13
WHERE CDEQUIPE = 741
AND CDSITUACAO NOT IN (8)
```

Como fazer para que ele me traga apenas os registros dos chamados encerrados dos ultimos 3 meses apartir da data ATUAL?

Comment: Pesquisev por add_months .. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas considerando que o campo DTTERMINO seja um datetime, você pode usar o comando sysdate (que pega a data atual) e subtrair 90 dias (3 meses).

Então é só fazer um filtro onde a data deve estar após a data atual - 90 dias. A consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DTCHAMADO AS DT_ABERTO,
       DTTERMINO AS DT_ENCERRADO, 
       CDCHAMADO AS CHAMADO, 
       NMTITULOCHAMADO AS TITULO, 
       NMRESPONSAVEL AS RESPONSÁVEL, 
       NMSITUACAO AS SITUAÇÃO
FROM VW_HD_CHAMADO13
WHERE CDEQUIPE = 741
AND CDSITUACAO NOT IN (8)
AND DTTERMINO >= sysdate - 90
```